# HTACCESS Redirect (moved folders) - Recursion Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a ready made theme for my site. I am in need to move the images/js/css folder to a specific folder.

Currently it is as such:

```
|- application
|- assets
    |- img
    |- css
    |- js
|- system
```

The theme is such that the the img/css/js folders are int he root folder.

With the expectation to route requests to the img/css/js folders I wrote some thing like this in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(images|robots\.txt|assets)

RewriteRule img/(.*) /assets/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule js/(.*) /assets/js/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But I noticed that there is a recursion happening. From

`[Fri May 03 11:56:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

How could I avoid the recursion. I noticed changing the folder name helps, but prefer some thing via `.htaccess`.

I am not very good with regular expressions, but I remember there are ways to say NOT in it. For example saying `redirect urls comming for 'img' folder but NOT having 'assets' in it should be redirected to 'assets/img' folder.`

BTW, do you know how costly these `.htaccess` rules are performance wise. I mean, is it a bad idea to have it so etc.

Thanks in advance, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rewrite condition only gets applied to the immediately following rule, so you need to replicate the condition for both your **img** and **js** rules:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|robots\.txt|assets)
RewriteRule img/(.*) /assets/img/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(images|robots\.txt|assets)
RewriteRule js/(.*) /assets/js/$1 [L]
```

Or you can change your pattern to include the beginning of the URI:

```
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) /assets/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) /assets/js/$1 [L]
```